# SOAPUi and keystore

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, soapui, pem

Recently, i had to enhance SOAP communications between me and a web service.
After creating a private key file on my server and after CSR was created/sent, a certificate  file was received in PEM format.

I want to test it in SOAPUi but it keeps saying that **Error: Access is Denied. Client SSL Certificate Required**.

Here what i did :

- Certificate conversion

  ```
  openssl pkcs12 -export -out **certif.p12** -inkey **myprivatekey.pem** -in **Certificate-received.pem**
  ```
- Keystore import

  ```
  keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass **changeit** -destkeypass **changeit** -destkeystore **pierrejks.jks** -srckeystore **certif.p12** -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass **tenzin** -alias 1
  ```

In SOAPUi,

I went to **preferences** and in **SSL Settings** Tab,

- keystore was set to be pierrejks.jks
- keystore password provided :  **changeit**
- requires client authentication was ticked.

On the project now ( Right click on project's root then Show Project View), i went to **WS-Security Configurations**, **keystore** tab to add a new source.

- Source is the path to **pierrejks.jks** file
- Password is **changeit**
- Defaults Alias is set to pierrealias
- No Alias Password provided

After filling these information, **status** became ok

In the **Outgoing WS-Security Configurations**, a configuration was added with a new **WSS-Entry Encryption**.

- Configuration Name is **pierreconf**
- WSS Entry type is **Encryption**
- Keystore choosen is **pierrejks.jks**
- Alias is **1**
- password is **changeit**

Finally, a request is made with **pierreconf** Outgoing WSS profile and this is were i have the error. 
At this moment, if i understand correctly, RAW tab shows that it is encrypted :

```
POST https://gsxapi.apple.com/gsx-ws/services/emea/iphone HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:authenticate"
Content-Length: 3047
Host: gsxapi.apple.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:glob="http://gsxws.apple.com/elements/global" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-974B3C3F270F85DA2A143289398095719" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><ds:X509Data><ds:X509IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=US,O=Apple Inc.,OU=Certification Authority,CN=Apple Corporate External Authentication CA 1</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>6119460251051586160</ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509IssuerSerial></ds:X509Data></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>yWIQ5aWqy50ba/kaw3mLYyvpBL8S+mcQnkZri8q6deJXoNFZm+TGOry9ds5VCbsYzpgjAYGFRZxnEfnAirFDqojUgbthc6E/YeG15y1GShiBZrBB3U5KVk6ZIqRaOAVSBMCG5DXosFDz0I/MrToMA8MvX5A26pgp6siM6fhfVRLfFPDCJQOQJw3gr2G3IUnu0t4jf2BIs4FPObtOZSN1ou+w3ny2meL2F0VhT2UPDbZ46EKwHiY7Az9RVt0MocWRRQSR9FU4h6zqziWbUC95OrzrKXrbo01La8UDZ4mykQXqg==</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData><xenc:ReferenceList><xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-974B3C3F270F85DA2A143289398095720"/></xenc:ReferenceList></xenc:EncryptedKey></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-974B3C3F270F85DA2A143289398095720" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-974B3C3F270F85DA2A143289398095719"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Return message is

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
Connection: close
Content-Length: 57
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Pragma: no-cache

Error: Access is Denied. Client SSL Certificate Required.
```

How to use SSL is not clear to me at the moment.

I'm sure i did some mistakes, can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: You need to use the certificate provided by the web service.  Creating your own and just using it is a bit like trying to unlock your car with the wrong key

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for sharing.
Certificate-received.pem has been provided by Apple to contact their web service. It has been created after a CSR has been generated on my side (with my private key file)
I did not create a new file, but it has been converted to PKCS12 because it seems that keytool can't import PEM file directly within a keystore.
Pierre

Answer (score 15):

Done it !

Info : My SOAPUi version is 5.0
I decided not to use a JKS as keystore but p12 file only

Here is step by step what i did

**PKCS12 file creation**

Using my privatekey.pem file ( used to generate CSR file ) and certificate.pem received ( Generated by thirs party given previous CSR File )

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certif.p12 -inkey myprivatekey.pem -in Certificate-received.pem
```

On question :

- `Enter pass phrase for myprivatekey.pem` : i did enter password used to generate my private key.
- `Enter export password` : **tenzin**
- `Verifying - Enter Export Password` : **tenzin**

**In SOAP UI**,

In preferences,

1. **certif.p12** was choosen as keystore.
2. Password given is **tenzin**
3. Requires client authentication is ticked.

It works.

Comment: Alright! It's working for me as well. Note you don't have to add authorization settings on the request, only in the global preferences!

Comment: There seems to be a problem by using jks keystores aus identity provider. Using the PKCS#12 works fine for my. Thanks

Comment: got it working.  .cer doesn't contain private key. and pfx doesn't work. I had to convert to p12  file, and then soapUI worked.